# Are there libraries available for processing(reading) Excel 2003 XML documents

Tags: c#, excel, .net-3.5, excel-2003

We have a situation where **Excel's XML 2003 format** is widely used for file uploads to a third party system. There is a requirement that some information needs to be extracted from these files for other processing. Are there any libraries available that process Excel's 2003 XML format?

Further detail: the format of these XML files have been defined by the third party and we cannot change it. In addition, the data itself is not tabular or in any consistent format.

I have previously used `System.Xml.Linq` to extract data (basically a row, column index approach) from very simple versions of these XML spreadsheets. The data required now is from more complex versions which include merged cells, named ranges etc.

This processing is done on a server, thus Interop is not an option based on this [infamous MS KB about Excel on a server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Can someone also suggest an approach to processing these files?

Comment: Excel's a pretty good one. Why do you have to use a different 3rd-party library?

Comment: Server-side processing via asp.net and AFAIK using Excel Interop libraries requires Excel to be installed on a server and that's not recommended (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: Agreed, a perfectly valid reason. (I just didn't see that in your question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eventual solution required me to create an XSLT to extract the required data from the file and transform to a very simple XML representation of the data. I also created classes that represented the object model for the deserialzation of the generated XML using `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()`.

However, for this to work effectively, an update was required to the source Excel XML files to include Named Ranges for the cells that needed to be extracted.Having the Name Ranges allowed for a more simpler XSLT, however the biggest code-smell is the dependency on the existence of the Named Ranges in a file I don't control.

A high level overview of the code

```
   XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument("path to Excel xml file");
   XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

   StringReader sr = new StringReader(Resources.XSLT); // embedded resource, the xslt is read in as a string
   XmlTextReader xs = new XmlTextReader(sr);
   xslt.Load(xs);
   XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
                                    {
                                        Indent = true,
                                        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                                        OmitXmlDeclaration = false
                                    };

   MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
   using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(memStream, settings))
   {
       xslt.Transform(doc, writer); // the simple xml..almost there 
   }

   MyCustomClass curve;
   {
       XmlSerializer deSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyCustomClass));
       // reset needed to beginning of mem stream since current position is the last write position
       memStream.Position = 0; 
       curve = (MyCustomClass)deSerializer.Deserialize(memStream);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) tool with your studio to generate classes for easily reading the xml files?

It won't include any smart logic for combining fields of course-- but the benefit is that you won't need to build your own reading logic or install interop libraries.

Comment: Am I missing something - the xml files already have a defined schema which is present in every xml spreadsheet `Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"`. What would this help me achieve?

Comment: the xsd.exe tool won't generate a schema but will generate .cs CSharp code to deserialize the office files into, well, a set of classes which you can manipulate. I haven't used it with office files but it works very well for example with my countries's tax file format which is a hierarchy of various elements.

Comment: I think the problem is hierarchy - my files have none. It's just data in xml format following the MS schema. Think of it as a report, where you can have information and data at very random places in the spreadsheeet.

Comment: Good idea, but I could only get XSD.exe to generate a .XSD file and not any class files.  It errored and said: Error: Can only generate one of classes or datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Check if [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex does what you require. I'm using it to import simple lists of data from Excel into one of our applications.

Comment: Nope, not useful. Can be used for 2003's binary formats (.xls) and not the .xml

Comment: Apose Cells then? http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx. They are supposed to support Excel 2003's SpreadsheetML format.